# Unity Options Menu - Button UI - Highlighting Enabled Button

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating an "Option" menu for my Snake game.  I have 2 categories: 1) Difficulty and 2) Walls (user can choose solid walls or wrap around). If my game is set to Easy and Solid, I want these 2 buttons to be highlighted.

Please share with me ideas on how you went about doing this.  Using Unity button's default transition settings, I find I can only highlight 1 button out of the 4 (maybe it is because they are all on the same canvas?).  What are some effective ways to build an interactive options that checks your settings and highlight the proper buttons?

[image: option menu]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Solution.

1 - Use **Toggle** instead of **Button**.

2 - Scale the background of Toggle to look like button.

3 - Instead of **Tick Mark** use a bigger outline (to show glow) Image.

4 - Add **Toggle Group** in inspector to easy button. Set Toggle Group of Easy and Hard Button to group. Set IsOn property of Hard to OFF state. (This was only one button can be selected at one time).

5 - Add another **Toggle Group** to solid, repeat the same for solid and wrap buttons.

6. On starting the game, read the states of the buttons.